# youtube api end of video load a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, api, youtube

I am trying to use the YouTube API to detect when a video ends and then to call a JS function I have to then load another one. The call function is in another JS document which is in the head of my HTML document.
This is the code I have so far from the API site but I am really confused with it.

```
<pre><code> <script>




var ytfullplayer;
    function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
        console.log('onYouTubePlayerAPIReady');
        ytfullplayer = new YT.Player('myVid', {
            events: {

              if ''onStateChange': getVideo

            }
        });

    }
    function getVideo(); }


</script> </code> </pre>
```

I have called the youtube api in the head of my page. But I am not 100% sure if it goes there.
Any assistance would be nice.
I am using an  for my youtube video.

Cheers
Matt

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The API provides an example of what you're attempting beneath [Subscribing to Events](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#SubscribingEvents):

```
function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
  ytplayer = document.getElementById("myytplayer");
  ytplayer.addEventListener("onStateChange", "onytplayerStateChange");
}

function onytplayerStateChange(newState) {
   alert("Player's new state: " + newState);
}
```

Bind your custom function as the handler to the "onStateChange" event, and evaluate the new state from within. According to the Events portion of the API, you're looking for state `0`, indicating the video has ended.

```
function onytplayerStateChange(newState) {
   if ( newState == 0 ) {
     /* load next video */
  }
}
```