# Execute Javascript function after youtube video end

Tags: jquery, youtube

I am loading up a youtube video through the youtube API, as I want to execute a line of jQuery when the video ends. For some reason my code will not execute, can someone point me in the right direction...

First I embed the iFrame

```
 <iframe id="player" class="blo" width="219" height="207" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/qNL81Khx_UE?enablejsapi" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Then I create the API Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
          // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
          var tag = document.createElement('script');
          tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/player_api";
          var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
          firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

          // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
          //    after the API code downloads.
          var player;
          function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
            player = new YT.Player('player', {
              height: '390',
              width: '640',
              videoId: 'qNL81Khx_UE',
              events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
              }
            });
          }
          </script>
```

Then I make a function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var myPlayerState;
  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
      alert('Something Happened');
    }
    myPlayerState = event.data;
     }

if (myPlayerState == 1){
alert('Something Happened');
}
```

Can anyone let me know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: I hope this useful

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10459622/youtube-api-end-of-video-load-a-function